# Inserting data to MySQL table from multi-language HTML form via PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have *HTML* form as below:

[image: sample form]

For now there are 3 languages in future will be more, fields with prefix `_lang` are generating dynamically.

These are input fields (`name_en`, `name_ru`, etc. are placeholders).

MySQL tables looks like:

`Parent` table

```
Id    UserId
```

`Details` table

```
Id    ParentId    Name     Description    Language
```

I would like to insert data to `Details` like this:

```
Id    ParentId    Name     Description    Language
1     1           FooEn    FooBarEn       EN
2     1           FooRu    FooBarRu       RU
3     1           FooFr    FooBarFr       FR
```

And to `Parent` table like this:

```
Id    UserId
1     123
```

After form submitted I can insert successfully data to `Parent` table. I've faced a problem with inserting this data to `Details` table. I don't have idea how could I merge `name_en` and `description_en` as 1 entry.

In PHP I have `$language_array` with all possible languages (for this example `en`, `ru`, `fr`) also I'm using `substr` to get language code from data, but what next? Should I use `foreach` somehow?

```
foreach($language_array as $k=>$v) {
   // there I've missed my mind
}
```

First time I've faced HTML form structure like this. Please, give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to retrieve the form fields from your `$_POST` data.

Assuming your `$_POST` data has the following structure.

```
Array
(
    [name_en] => name_en
    [name_ru] => name_ru
    [name_fr] => name_fr
    [description_en] => description_en
    [description_ru] => description_ru
    [description_fr] => description_fr
)
```

You can then use your `$language_array` to iterate over and extract the associated `$_POST` form field values like so: `$_POST['fieldname_' . $lang]`

```
$languages = ['en', 'fr', 'ru'];
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `table_name` (`Name`, `Description`, `Language`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $name, $description, $language);
    foreach ($languages as $lang) {
       $name = array_key_exists('name_' . $lang, $_POST) ? $_POST['name_' . $lang] : null;
       $description = array_key_exists('description_' . $lang, $_POST) ? $_POST['description_' . $lang] : null;
       $language = strtoupper($lang);
       mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
}
```

> For details on `mysqli` and usage on prepared statements, please see
>   the [PHP
>   documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

---

An alternate solution would be to create a listing of form fields that you want to have displayed to the user.

```
$fields = ['name' => 'Name', 'description' => 'Description'];
$languages = ['en', 'ru', 'fr'];
```

Then you can iterate over each field and language to render them in the browser.

> Take note that the input field names are prefixed with their associated language
>   as an array of fields, such as `LANG[field]`

```
foreach ($fields as $fieldName => $section) {
    echo '<fieldset>';
    echo '<legend>' . $section. '</legend>';
    foreach ($languages as $language) {
        $inputName = strtoupper($language) . '[' . $fieldName . ']';
        $placeholder = $fieldName  . '_' . $language;
        echo '<p>';
        echo '<label>';
        echo '<input type="text" name="' . $inputName . '" placeholder="' . $placeholder . '"/>';
        echo '</label>';
        echo '</p>';
    }
    echo '</fieldset>';
}
```

Resulting Form:

[image: Form Example]

Your `$_POST` data would then have the following structure

```
Array
(
    [EN] => Array
        (
            [name] => name_en
            [description] => description_en
        )

    [RU] => Array
        (
            [name] => name_ru
            [description] => description_ru
        )

    [FR] => Array
        (
            [name] => name_fr
            [description] => description_fr
        )

)
```

This would then allow you to insert individual entries for each language, by iterating over the `$_POST` form values, as an array of language associated form fields.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `table_name` (`Name`, `Description`, `Language`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $name, $description, $language);
    foreach ($_POST as $language => $fields) {
       $name = array_key_exists('name', $fields) ? $fields['name'] : null;
       $description = array_key_exists('description', $fields) ? $fields['description'] : null;
       mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
}
```

---

*Disclaimer: As there was little information provided on what the `parent` table relates to or its association(s), it was excluded from my answer. I presume the OP will be able to determine how to manipulate the answer to satisfy adding the parent to the query.*